# Given Fourier series coefficients, what is the maximum value the constructed signal can have?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Given Fourier series coefficients $a_1, a_2, \dots, b_1,b_2, \dots$, what is the maximum value the constructed signal can have?

[image]

I am interested in normalizing this signal for which knowing this maximum value makes it possible for me. Another solution for me could also be enforcing a relation between the coefficients so that the resulting signal has a maximum value of one, but I don't know what relation.

A heuristic way for me is of course also to construct the signal on a grid and pick the maximum.

In the end I may only have 10 to 20 coefficients in total, not more. I am not sure though what relation I can enforce between the coefficients. The coefficients are bonded between [0,1]

Comment: Triangle inequality says $|F(x)| \leq \frac{|a_0|}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n| + |b_n|$, but it's not helpful if the coefficients are not absolutely convergent.

Comment: It much depends on the characteristics of the series $a_{n}, b_{n}, \sqrt{a_{n}^2+b_{n}^2}$: are they decreasing ? how fast?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3406127/339790 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/58512844/6338725

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/q/143342/91764

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Please leave my posts alone. Not everyone is as smart as you but if they don't agree with you, don't be so obsessive about it.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Dude, I'm not saying you're wrong, but if I want my post written in a way, I don't have to explain to everyone why. You made your suggestion on how I can write better or in the right way. It is my own choice to follow your suggestion or not. leave my posts alone.

Comment: @alireSaRanjbar Math SE does not belong to you. People decide to click on questions or not based on title and tags. Incorrect titles and tagging do waste people's time. You do not have the right to waste other people's time with impunity.

Answer (score 1):

You could imagine the two terms (cos and sin) being in the same mode to describing describe an ellipses in 2D. Whereby $a_n$ and $b_n$ express the size of the axis. Now you could  heuristically limit the normalizing constant to be between $\sum_{i=1}^n{\max(a_n,b_n)}$ (when all of the coefficients are very different in magnitude) and $\sqrt{2} \sum_{i=1}^n{\max(a_n,b_n)}$ (when all of the coefficients are the same in magnitude)

Comment: but then how do I find the normalizing constant.

Comment: My argument would be that the $\sqrt{2}$ term is the absolute maximum term you can construct, since the normalizing constant can only be in that interval you could use that for normalization purposes.

Comment: Beside, you could run some test to verify this with the mentioned number of coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a closed formula for the maximum, in the general case.
You added that you have between 10 to 20 coefficients (suppose you count the pairs).

With a modern CAS such an amount of coefficients is quite manageable. Take the shortest period, divide it by a suitable factor (say $10$) and compute the sequence of the signal values at $x=k \tau$. Find the absolute maximum and eventually refine the search around it.

Alternatively, speaking of approximated methods, find the power of signal, and determine in which frequencies it concentrates.
If these are a phew, and the remaining frequencies account for a small portion of the power, then you can concentrate the analysis on the more powerful and regard the others as noise (more or less white) for the amplitude of which there are statistical estimates.

Otherwise, just knowing that the coefficients range in $[0,1]$ you can analyze the whole signal statistically.

Comment: In the end I may only have 10 to 20 coefficients in total, not more. I am not sure though what relation I can enforce between the coefficients. The coefficients are bonded between [0,1]